# WiFi not working on Latitude D620

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dell, network-manager

I have an old Dell Latitude D620 that I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on.  I had originally installed the Ubuntu 12.04 Server configuration, than added in the desktop stuff later with "apt-get install ubuntu-desktop".

If I have a hard-wired connection, the WiFi also works, at least as far as seeing my WiFi SID and authenticating via WPA.  But, if I disconnect the wired connection and reboot, I don't get any networking at all.

During boot, I get console messages saying, "Waiting for network configuration...", followed by "Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...".  When the system finally comes up, ifconfig shows eth0 UP, and lists wan0, but it's not UP.  There's no WiFi widget in my toolbar.  And, if I open the Network control panel, I get a frowny face and "The system network service are not compatible with this version".

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Open Up System Settings From The Dash.

Click On Software & Updates

Tab To Additonal Drivers. Select A Broadcom Wifi Driver Or Any Other Driver Listed That Has Network In Its Name.

Click Activate.

Let Me Know If It Helps!

Comment: No joy on the Additional Drivers.  All it found were some NVIDIA graphics drivers.

Comment: @RoySmith What Wifi Card Do You Have?